# Is there any good effect when put an img tag in a p tag ? is it correct at all?

Tags: html

I don't understand why some put an image tag inside a p tag ... 
Is there any benefits?

```html
<p>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e7/36/58/e736580683c04f5df858b0f1bbba6344.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" >

</p>
```

Comment: it's largely a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` (paragraph) element is used for blocks of text.
Its children can be a `text` node, and ideally `inline` nodes (eg: `<span>` and `<a>`, others).

**Additionally**

In a paragraph we can also have some text with the related image, so adding an `<img>` element within a paragraph is also "valid" from a technical point of view but it might be tricky to justify if the image is the **only element** of that paragraph.  Usually in these cases the image elements is set to be `float: [left, right];` to allow the text to flow around them, but again it's a matter of preference.

**To answer your question**

It is technically valid html code to nest an `<img>` element inside a `<p>`; but it might be semantically inaccurate (depends on case by case).

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on the page in question. Sometimes it could be useful so that it inherits the style or positioning of the p tags. You could always accomplish it using other CSS rules but sometimes just putting a p tag around it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful for a scenario in which you want to center the image on the page or within a `div`. There may be better ways of achieving this, but you could do something like:

```html
<p style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
<img style=" height:300px; width:300px; float:none; margin:auto;" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e7/36/58/e736580683c04f5df858b0f1bbba6344.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" >
</p>
```

If you removed the `<p></p>` then the image would no longer be centered.

```html
<img style=" height:300px; width:300px; float:none; margin:auto;" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e7/36/58/e736580683c04f5df858b0f1bbba6344.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px" >
```